# Clustering time-stamped event-sequences of unequal size in r

Tags: r, events, cluster-analysis, sequences

I have really tried to find a somewhat specific answer to this, but it seems I always run into the problem, that comparing time-stamped event sequences is a very difficult task.

I have a number of pigeons, and I have recorded their behaviour over a period of time (not the same period of time for all pigeons, and not the same length of the time-intervals).

Now, the task is to cluster different behavioural patterns based on the sequence of events . The dataset has the following format:

Pigeon Number - Timestamp - Event-Type

Pigeon 1 - 05.07.17  05:06:43 - Fly up on stick

Pigeon 1 - 05.07.17  05:08:54 - Purr

Pigeon 2 - 05.07.17  05:10:21 - Purr

Pigeon 1 - 05.07.17  05:15:04 - Fly down from stick

Pigeon 3 - 05.07.17  05:21:15 - Fly down from stick

I have timestamps over a period of several years, I have 200.000 pigeons and 20 event-types, so it is a large dataset, but I can always start with a subset.

My question is: is there any way in R to analyse this type of data without having to bruteforce a clustering algorithm into R?

Comment: Exactly what type of clustering algorithm do you want to use? This question doesn't seem like a specific programming question that's right for Stack Overflow. If you don't know how you want to analyze your data, you might get help from the statisticians over at [stats.se] but you'd need to describe exactly what you want these "clusters" to represent.